# some Jquery code works on browser, but not on WebView Android and some does

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-studio

1. I have an Android Application containing a Webview.
2. Webview contains html page that uses Jquery.

First i want to tell you that jquery works to some extent, let me prove you.

I have a html title with its proper id, when the document is ready i change the color of the title by adding a css color class with jquery.

```
<h1 id="title">Hardcoded Title </h1>
 ------------
 $("#title").css('color', 'red');
```

**The Problem**

I also have a html5 player, i retrieve it with jquery and get the currentSrc, which contains the Url to the video.

*not so important but here is the player*

```
<div class="flowplayer">
        <video id="sourceVideo">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="http://view.vzaar.com/5456131/video" />
        </video>
    </div>
```

Now using some more jquery and a js called flowplayer.min.js i call a method to retrieve the player and grab its src property.

```
var video = $('#sourceVideo')[0];
var currentSrc = video.currentSrc;
```

I then proceed to apend the currentSrc to the title of my application.

```
$("#tituloPrueba").append(" - CurrentSrc : "+currentSrc);
```

When i checked in chrome, this is the result.
As you can see the append and color change work fine, as well as the variable that stores the value of currentSrc.

[image]

**Emulator**

If i just append text or change the color, everything seems to work fine.

[image]

But as soon as i call this line of code

```
  var video = $('#sourceVideo')[0];
  var currentSrc = video.currentSrc;(this one is the problem)
```

it seems as if jquery stops working?

Any ideas?

*Note*

Loading external js seems to work, i created a new js with a document ready and inside jquery code to change color of title and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

- First, check android webview version.
- Second, see what properties are available for the video tag.

Alternately, try to do this:

```
 alert( JSON.stringify(video) );
```

I assume the issue you have is that currentSrc is undefined, either because the tag video is not supported, or because that attribute is not present.

Even though, I am not quite clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i am trying to change the src of a video with jquery, the thing is $("#sourceVideo").attr("src")); returns undefined in webview, but it returns the actual value when rendered in chrome...

Comment: have you tried this: $('#sourceVideo').attr('src','newsrc');?

Comment: Ok, when i use the JSON.stringify(video), it shows the whole set of properties in browser, but in webview it displays nothing, most surely is a problem with the video player object? with the flowplayer.min.js in side webviews?

Comment: if it shows nothing on the webview, it may be that video tag is not supported in that version, what is the android version?

Comment: i tried API 22 AND 23 android 5.0 and 6.0 Marshmellow and lollypop

Comment: basically try: android:hardwareAccelerated="true"